# How to store or send text to tomcat server from html text form?

Tags: javascript, web-services, api, rest, tomcat

I'm developing api and stuck with next problem, I use tomcat as server and there are some java api functions and html page on server. I need to get text from user input into text field on html page and send this text to api function, or at least store this text on server. I've tried this, to post getted text to api:

```
 <button onclick=" myFunction() " id="button_submit" ">Enter</button>

  <script>
function myFunction() {
    var txt =  document.getElementById("some_id").value;
      xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost:8080/test/webapi/myresource",true);
      xmlhttp.send(txt);
     }
</script>
```

But my API function doesn't get any requests. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I already got what I wanted but I used xmlhttp open method with another signature like `http.open("POST", "url", true,username,pass);`

But still can't figure out why previous open method doesn't work for me, good luck